# Nvidia Optimus, can i use only the integrated card through vmware?

Tags: vmware, nvidia-optimus

i am running Ubuntu 11.10 through Vmware worksation 8. when i run Ubuntu, it runs in unity2d, and there are propriety drivers available. is this another optimus conflict? and if so, how can i go around it if optimus doesn't work in vms?

Comment: Uhm.. no you install the Guest Additions of Vmware to have 3D acceleration, has nothing to do with whatever GPU you have.

Comment: nevermind, apparently vmware currently has no support for unity, for whatever reason. looks like virtualbox it is *sigh*

Comment: Did you mean "discrete card" instead of "integrated card"? Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/82576/6969

Answer (score 1):

According to the OP:

> nevermind, apparently vmware currently has no support for unity, for
>   whatever reason. looks like virtualbox it is

The problem is with VM Ware and not Ubuntu or the drivers.