# Virtualbox crashing when run through optirun (virtualgl)

Tags: virtualbox, bumblebee

I have followed the virtualgl documentation to run virtualbox through virtualgl.  My goal is to use the discrete nvidia card in my laptop via optirun (bumblebee), which uses virtualgl to do this.  Attempting it has consistantly caused virtualbox to crash, as it can't find a graphics card.  Anyone knowledgeable about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IronHide / BumbleBee with a VirtualBox VM. Will it pass through video acceleration to the physical card?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/82576/ironhide-bumblebee-with-a-virtualbox-vm-will-it-pass-through-video-accelerati)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo usermod -a -G bumblebee your_login
```